# How big can a wedge of 2-forms be?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, exterior-algebra

The comass of a 2-form $\alpha$ is the maximal value of $\alpha(u,v)$
for a pair of unit vectors $u,v$.  The symplectic form $\alpha$ on
$\mathbb R^{2n}$ has the property that $|\alpha^{\wedge n}| = n!$.
For example, in $\mathbb R^6$ one has $|\alpha^{\wedge 3}| = 6$.  Are
there 2-forms $a,b,c$ of unit comass on $\mathbb R^6$ such that
$|a\wedge b\wedge c|>6$ ?

Note.  A solution is provided at https://mathoverflow.net/a/448681/28128

Comment: Your guess is max of comass $\leq \dim M$?

Comment: @C.F.G No, one could conjecture that one gets $n!$ if $M$ is of dimension $2n$.

Comment: Equivalently, the comass of $\alpha$ is the spectral radius (the largest absolute value of an (imaginary) eigenvalue) of the corresponding antisymmetric matrix.

Comment: What happens in $\mathbb R^4$? That would be helpful as context for your question.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes in $\mathbb R^4$ one can prove that $2$ is the largest possible value.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I am interested in to see its proof if it is short?

Comment: @C.F.G In $\mathbb R^4$ one has $|a\wedge b| = \langle a, \ast b\rangle$ where $\ast$ is the Hodge star, and one applies Cauchy-Schwarz together with the fact that the ratio between the Euclidean norm and the comass is at most $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @mr_e_man An additional case that can be proved is in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ when there are only two distinct forms, i.e., $a^k \wedge b^{n-k}$.

Comment: Looks relevant: https://www.magnusson.io/post/exterior-product-norm/

Comment: What is wrong with scaling i.e. $\lambda \alpha$ with CoMass$(\alpha)=1$?

Comment: @C.F.G I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: $|\lambda a\wedge \lambda b\wedge \lambda c|>6$. Or in case of symplectic form, what is wrong with $|\lambda \alpha^{\wedge 3}| $?

Comment: The forms are assumed to be of comass 1.  If you multiply them by $\lambda$, that condition is violated.

Comment: The norm is also multiplied by $\lambda$.

Comment: As mr_e_man says, if we equate $2$-forms with skew symmetric matrices, then the comass is the spectral radius (norm of largest eigenvalue). In fact, we can assume WLOG that all of the eigenvalues are $\pm i$. Proof: A general skew $2n \times 2n$ symmetric matrix $A$ can always be written as $U J(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n) U^T$, where $J$ is block diagonal  with $2 \times 2$ blocks of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \lambda_i \\ - \lambda_i & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $U_i$ is orthogonal. The condition that $A$ has co-mass $\leq 1$ means that $-1 \leq \lambda_i \leq 1$. (Continued.)

Comment: Now, suppose that we have skew symmetric matrices $A_1$, $A_2$, ... $A_n$, and write $A_i = U_i J(\lambda_{i1}, \ldots, \lambda_{in}) U_i^T$ as above. We want to maximize $| A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge A_n|$. Consider keeping the $U_i$ fixed and letting the $\lambda_i$ vary. The wedge product is multilinear in the $\lambda_i$, so the maximum for fixed $U_i$ must occur when all the $\lambda_i$ are on the boundary, meaning at $\pm 1$.

Comment: In other words, our goal is to maximize $| J_1 \wedge J_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge J_n|$, where $J_i$ are orthogonal matrices with $J^2 = -\text{Id}$. The easy bound is $n^n$, the conjectured bound is $n!$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer thanks for your comments.  Note that I did not literally conjecture the bound, even in dimension 6, but rather asked if it is true :-).  I think it has a better chance of being true in dimension 6 than in general.

Comment: Why is this question on math.stackexchange.com and not MathOverflow?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/448770/613